# Pasar Parametros PHP y MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, phpmailer

Estoy trabajando con PHP y MYSQL, en donde estoy intentando enviar un correo con PHPMAILER. El problema que tengo es que realizo la consulta e intento pasar el dato correo_usuario al destinatario de correo y me aparece error. La parte del correo esta funcionando bien, lo he probado ingresando un destinatario directamente y lo hace bien, pero al pasarle parametros no pasa.
Mi código es el siguiente:

```
 <?php 
   include "../conexion.php";
   require 'vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
   require 'vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
   require 'vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';
   use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
   use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

   $squery = mysqli_query($conection,"SELECT id_formulario, nombre_usuario, correo_usuario, 
   dd_mm_inicio FROM departamento WHERE id_formulario = 5 ");

   while($data = mysqli_fetch_object($squery))
   {
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;    // Activar autenticación SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.office365.com';   // SMTP Server
    $mail->Username   = 'mi correo';     // Cuenta SMTP
    $mail->Password   = 'mi password';    // Password de la cuenta
    $mail->isHTML(true);

    $mail->ClearAllRecipients(); // Elimina direcciones anteriores si se usa iteradamente
    $mail->setFrom('Sistema');
    **$mail->addAddress($data['correo_usuario']);**
    $mail->Subject  = 'Solicitud Rechazada';

    $Message = '<html><head>'.PHP_EOL;
    $Message .= '</head><body>'. PHP_EOL;
    $Message .= 'Le informamos que su Solicitud generada el en Formulario 555555' . PHP_EOL;
    $Message .= '</body></html>'. PHP_EOL;

    $mail->Body = $Message;
    $mail->send();
   }
 ?>

 El error es el siguiente:
 PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in 
 /var/www/sistema.uicc.ua/sistema/correo.php:27
 Stack trace:
 #0 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/sistema.uicc.ua/sistema/correo.php on line 27
```

Comment: Si usas `mysqli_fetch_object()`, tienes que usar la sintaxis `$data->nombreDeColumna` para obtener los datos, por ejemplo: `$data->correo_usuario`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta de la siguiente manera, vamos a utilizar `mysqli_fetch_array()` en `while`, de esta manera se va a enviar el correo cada vez que se itere un destinatario nuevo.

De igual manera aqui te dejo una guia proporcionada por PHPMailer de [Como enviar una lista de email](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps)

```
<?php 
   include "../conexion.php";
   require 'vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
   require 'vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
   require 'vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';
   use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
   use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

   $squery = mysqli_query($conection,"SELECT id_formulario, nombre_usuario, correo_usuario, 
   dd_mm_inicio FROM departamento WHERE id_formulario = 5 ");

   $mail = new PHPMailer();
   $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
   $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
   $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;    // Activar autenticación SMTP
   $mail->Host       = 'smtp.office365.com';   // SMTP Server
   $mail->Username   = 'mi correo';     // Cuenta SMTP
   $mail->Password   = 'mi password';    // Password de la cuenta
   $mail->isHTML(true);
   $mail->setFrom('Sistema');

   while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($squery))
   {

    $mail->ClearAllRecipients(); // Elimina direcciones anteriores si se usa iteradamente
    $mail->addAddress($data['correo_usuario']);**
    $mail->Subject  = 'Solicitud Rechazada';

    $Message = '<html><head>'.PHP_EOL;
    $Message .= '</head><body>'. PHP_EOL;
    $Message .= 'Le informamos que su Solicitud generada el en Formulario 555555' . PHP_EOL;
    $Message .= '</body></html>'. PHP_EOL;

    $mail->Body = $Message;
    $mail->send();
   }
 ?>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono..